# canceling Alarm in alarm manager?

Tags: android

When users enters and date and time it then puts it into alarm manager

```
public Manager(Context context){
       mContext = context;
       tolarmManager = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
       }

public void setSilent(Long id, Calendar when){

     Intent go = new Intent(mContext, someclass.class);
     PendingIntent golow = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mContext, 0 , i, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
    toAlarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, when.getTimeInMillis(), golow);
```

when the alarm is set how do i delete it from the alarm if i dont want alarm any more?

Answer (score 2):

```
int RC = alarmRequestCode; // your request code is 0
Intent intentAlarm = new Intent(context, AlarmReciever.class);
PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, RC, intentAlarm, 0);
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(context.ALARM_SERVICE);
alarmManager.cancel(sender);
```

Answer (score 0):

You do

```
toAlarmManager.cancel(golow);
```

which removes any alarms with the matching intent.

Comment: Is there anyway i can do this from remote file ... say that the code above is in text.java and i want to delete the alarm from inside test1.java , when i try     test.mAlarmManager.cancel(test.golow); or     test.mAlarmManager.cancel(golow); it does not work it cant find golow

Comment: You should be able to just recreate toAlarmManager and golow in the new class.  Alternatively, you could declare them as `public` variables in test.java and reference them that way.